# Validate string entry

Tags: excel, vba

I need to validate a Social Security Number (SSN) in Excel. I don't know where to start and I've looked everywhere on the web, but to no avail ... Please help if you can. Thanks.

Here are the validation rules:

- Field length always *9* numeric digits.
- Can not be all same digits (e.g. `222-22-2222`)
- Can not contain continuous, sequential numbers from `1 to 9` or `9 to 1` (i.e. `123-45-6789`, `9876-54-321`)
- Can not contain data other than numerical digits (`0-9`)
- Restricted numbers beginning with `666`, `000`.
- Can not contain 9 as the first number.`
- Last four digits can not be zeros `(0000)`.

Comment: What have you got so far? Please see the following functions in Excel: if (for checking conditions), and (for multiple conditions, len (for checking the length of the SSN), left and right (for getting specific characters in the SSN),  isnumeric (is a number)

Answer (score 1):

[regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) solution below that draws heavily from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/651609/Validating-Social-Security-Numbers-through-Regular)

I note that this condition

> *Can not contain continuous, sequential numbers from 1 to 9 or 9 to 1 (i.e. 123-45-6789, **9876-54-321**)*

is already invalidated by:

> Can not contain 9 as the first number.

***Using the code***

1. Press  <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> to go to the visual basic editor
2. *Insert* .... *Module*
3. Copy and Paste in the code starting from `Sub OCD_Kid()`
4. Press  <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> to get back to Excel

You can then use this User Defined Formula (UDF) to test values in your spreadsheet directly.

- If `A1` had `070-22-2794`,
- in `B1` enter =`OCD_Kid(A1)` to test the string in `A1`

*main code*

```
 Function OCD_Kid(strIn As String) As Boolean
 Dim objRegex As Object
 Set objRegex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
 With objRegex
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "^(?!\b(\d)\1+-(\d)\1+-(\d)\1+\b)(?!123-45-6789)(?!666|000|9\d{2})\d{3}-\d{2}-(?!0{4})\d{4}$"
    OCD_Kid = .test(strIn)
 End With
 End Function
```

*test*

```
 Sub Tested()
 Debug.Print OCD_Kid("222-22-2222") ' Invalid
 Debug.Print OCD_Kid("070-22-2794") ' Valid
 Debug.Print OCD_Kid("823-45-6789") ' Valid
 Debug.Print OCD_Kid("123-45-6789") ' Invalid
 Debug.Print OCD_Kid("123-45-5789") ' Valid
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is not a complete answer.**

However, it will give you a template you can expand to meet more criteria.  Here is a User Defined Function **(UDF)**

```
Public Function SSNCheck(s As String) As String
    Dim i As Long
    SSNCheck = "Bad"
    If Len(s) <> 11 Then Exit Function
    ary = Split(s, "-")
    If UBound(ary) <> 2 Then Exit Function
    For i = 0 To 2
        If Not IsNumeric(ary(i)) Then Exit Function
    Next i
    If Len(ary(0)) <> 3 Then Exit Function
    If Len(ary(1)) <> 2 Then Exit Function
    If Len(ary(2)) <> 4 Then Exit Function
    If ary(2) = "0000" Then Exit Function
    If ary(0) & ary(1) & ary(2) = "123456789" Then Exit Function
    SSNCheck = "Good"
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=SSNCheck(A1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

for specifics on UDFs

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**